# Yii Error 400 The CSRF token could not be verified when trying to delete the post

Tags: php, yii

When I was trying to delete a post I got this error:

```
Yii Error 400 The CSRF token could not be verified
```

I don't know what is exactly causing this and to what it could be related. here is my action delete:

```
    public function actionDelete($id) {

         if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
                // we only allow deletion via POST request
                $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

                // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
                if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
        }
        else
              throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }

    protected function afterDelete()
    {
        parent::afterDelete();
        Image::model()->deleteAll('name='.$this->id);
        Date::model()->deleteAll('tbl_show_id='.$this->id);
        Press::model()->deleteAll('tbl_show_id='.$this->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you've enabled [CSRF validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security#cross-site-request-forgery-prevention). If you want to use it, read the doc and make sure you send the CSRF token in every POST request.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue but the following solved it. Hope it helps.
I added

```
'params'=> array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken)
```

to the following code:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::linkButton('Delete',array(
        'submit'=>$this->createUrl('delete',array('id'=>$model->id)),
        'confirm'=>"Are you sure want to delete ".$item->product->name."from the shopping cart?",
        'params'=> array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken)));
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF will keep giving you this error because you're deleting by using a URL (GET)

In order to use CSRF validation, you should make your request using a valid form that generates the CSRF token and submits it with every post.

Lookup:
Yii CForm

Answer (score 0):

Even if you followed the Yii CSRF documentation correctly your error could be caused by a caching system. In my case the server cached the login page and then served the same token over and over again with the login form thus returning false on verification.

Comment: This was the issue in my app and is a valid edge case.