# Yii CSRF Token cannot be verified

Tags: php, ajax, post, yii, csrf

I had in my script a form which was submitted by ajax like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url:jQuery('form',modal).attr('action'),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        type:'post',
        data: {
            email:jQuery('input[name="email"]',modal).val(),
            something:jQuery('input[name="something"]',modal).val(),
            level:jQuery('select[name="level"]',modal).val(),
            YII_CSRF_TOKEN: jQuery('input[name="csrf"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('.message',modal).html(data.message).slideDown();
            if (!data.success){
                jQuery('input[name="email"]',modal).addClass('error');
            } else {
                jQuery('input[name="email"]',modal).removeClass('error');
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything was working great. Then today I was writing new function for deleting items from database. SO I wrote my php function (nothing extra complicated) and added jQuery ajax call to it triggered by clicking on link:

```
// ajax request
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:jQuery(this).attr('href'),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type:'post',
        data: {
            something:jQuery(this).attr('alt'),
            YII_CSRF_TOKEN:jQuery('input[name="csrf"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

Both, the link and the form are in the same view. But after adding the new function for deleting Everything kind of broke down. I cannot make any POST request to server, just having "Error: The CSRF token could not be verified". I cannot see the problem as I am passing the CSRF. The firebug log shows:

```
YII_CSRF_TOKEN  bf6d9bf62ee96f32e34a74244baca7f2f1bdd569
something   4
```

I might understand that the new function doesn't work for any reason, but why did the other function broke down as well, I cannot get.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153112/yii-error-400-the-csrf-token-could-not-be-verified-when-trying-to-delete-the-pos) might help.

Comment: I believe you can track the http requests/responses in firebug/firefox. Make sure that the cookies contains same value as form does.  that means  you can find a cookie with name "YII_CSRF_TOKEN"  and that should match with form's "YII_CSRF_TOKEN" value.

Comment: @SuVeRa at least someone took a second to really think about the issue, thank you. unfortunately everything you said i tried/check. value in cookie is the same, i ebeu tried to delete it but still same problem. there are some extra chars in cookie looking like encoded url (%20 etc) just few of them, i dont have it in hand right now, can try to track what is that

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out what the problem was and thought I would share it with you. Of course it was very trivial.

In the PHP function (action) the flow was going, and everytime it run into problem / not expected result (record doesn't exist etc.) it would return something like:

```
if (empty($user)){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>0,'message'=>'User does not exist'));
    return false;
}
```

I think that some of you see my mistake already. The problem is that once you

```
return false;
```

Yii automatically gives back message "Invalid Request".
Therefore, doesn't matter if you get or not everything done well on server side, you have to always return true. So

```
if (empty($user)){
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>0,'message'=>'User does not exist'));
    return true;
}
```

Works as expected.

For the problem with message "Error: The CSRF token could not be verified." I still don't understand what the problem is, but also found solution. I have realized that this message is returned in first instance I do any action with $_POST variable. Therefore what I did at the beginning of the actions is:

```
$post = $_POST;
```

Probably not the perfect solution, but it works.